# Freeing Dataframe memory in python

Tags: python, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have a folder which have a multiple flat files which have different mappings, I am trying to get the flat file in data frame one by one by reading the mapping from sql server, once the file is loaded I am uploading to the file to sql server, next I am moving the processed file to another folder, while doing this after reading several files, the program crashes with "memory error". I did try to delete the data frame every time the file is processed after that I use `gs.collect()` to explicitly release the memory used, but still I am getting the error. Below is the code snippet.

```
for df in pd.read_fwf(temp_processing_folder_path + '\\' + filename, colspecs=column_specs, header=None, names=column_names, dtype=str,
                 # na_values=' ', keep_default_na=False, encoding='utf-8')
                 na_values=' ', keep_default_na=False, encoding='utf-8', chunksize=200000):
    transfer_data_to_staging_tables(df, file_extension)
    print("working")
#i += 1
    #print(i)
print("done" )
del df
gc.collect()


def transfer_data_to_staging_tables(dataframe, file_type):
    dataframe.to_sql(file_type, con=engine, schema='maildat', if_exists='append', chunksize=100000)
```

Comment: have you tried low_memory_mode, ```low_memory=True```

Comment: Can you expand your explanation of the procedure? I’m not certain I understand it completely. Having more of your code, and possibly data, would also be good. See: [mcve].

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of that `del` statement? It will only delete the last DataFrame. Do you know if `read_fwf()` has been deprecated, or if its use is discouraged? The most recent docs have far fewer parameters documented than older versions.

Comment: The default data types are pretty data hungry.  Have you looked into whether you can change datatypes? Small Ints can drop to lower memory usage ints, and text which is often repeated can change to Category rather than object.